# How to install windows IBM db 2 database 32 bit on a 64 bit computer

Tags: db2

This launchpad is not intended to run on the current platform. Check the product documentation or contact your vendor for more information about supported platforms. 
Information about your machine
Operating System (top.OS) = 
Locale (top.LOCALE) = en
Launchpad compatibility version =

Compatibility checks defined for this launchpad
version = 9.7

It keeps showing this even after i use run as admin or run in compatibility .

Comment: What is the operating-system name and version.  There are rules here.

Answer (score 1):

The message can be returned when install DB2 V9.7 on Windows Server 2016.  Unfortunately, V9.7 is supported on Windows 2008, 2012, 8, 7 and some older versions of Windows according to below:
**System requirements for IBM Db2 for Linux, UNIX, and Windows** 
https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/system-requirements-ibm-db2-linux-unix-and-windows

And here is recommended Fix Packs list for each versions:
**Recommended Fix Packs for DB2 for Linux, UNIX and Windows**
https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/recommended-fix-packs-db2-linux-unix-and-windows

Here is key note from the link:
End of Support for DB2 Version 9.1 is April 30, 2012 More Info...
End of Support for DB2 Version 9.5 is April 30, 2015 More Info...
**End of Support for DB2 Version 9.7 is September 30, 2017** More Info...
End of Support for DB2 Version 10.1 is September 30, 2017 More Info...

Db2 V9.7 is out of support now so it is recommended to upgrade V11.1/V11.5 instead.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

RUN WINZIP  THEN AFTER EXTACTING go to the directory/path
C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\EXPC\db2\Windows THEN LOOK FOR DB2 Express -c

then run and it will install
this will avoid computer from checking compatibility

Answer (score 0):

I have just getting the same issue.
If you want to really install this V9.7 version, I have found a workaround, which works great for me.
You need to download a more recent version of Db2, says the Db2 V10.1 version. Then you extract the V10.1 archive and copy the file called "getOS.bat" from the following folder "C:\Temp\db2_10.1\SERVER\db2\Windows\launchpad" and then you paste this file into the same path for the V9.7 extracted archive folder. It works well for me (it seems that they have corrected the script for the OS determination). I hope it will work for you or other people !